# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.10 from USB key on Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 (2012 model)

Tags: live-usb, usb-creator

I'm new in the Linux community and thus, I wanted to try Ubuntu 12.10 by using a USB flash drive boot (used with LiLi Creator). I installed the ISO file using LiLi Creator on the USB key, but when rebooted my system, the usb drive didn't show up on the boot menu (F12), the usb key is just not there. I use Windows 8 Single Language and the system BIOS has two options UEFI and Legacy but those settings didn't help me booting from USB drive. The USB Emulation is enabled FYI, one last thing: I don't know more settings and Dell Community also dosen't have particular answer, please help me.

My config:
Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 Laptop (2012)
Intel Core i5 3rd gen @ 2.5GHz
4GB RAM
Intel HD 4000 graphics,
Windows 8 Single Language 64bit
Award BIOS A11 (I think I updated it to A11)
Transcend JetFlash 2GB for installing Ubuntu 12.10 with LiLi Creator

Thanks in advance :)
Rutul

Comment: you should start here if you want to use UEFI - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI. First thing is, you need to change the boot order. if you choose Legacy mode, you will not have any problem but you may need to resintall windows 8. but this will be easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a Dell Inspiron 15R (5520). When installed Ubuntu and Linux Mint from a USB drive by using Startup Disk Creator. Disable Secure Boot, change your settings to Legacy, then reboot with the USB image on your USB drive. Push the <kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>12</kbd> key for the boot menu and you should see your USB drive - highlight this and touch Enter and you should then be booting from the USB drive. This worked for me after much experimentation with different options. Hope this helps --

Answer (score 0):

If your drive didn't showed up on BIOS boot menu, that is probably faulty USB drive or faulty USB port.